# Complex $and and $or query in Mongo using PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to execute a mongo find with php using the $and operator combined with the $or operator, however I cant seem to figure out the way to execute it.  What this Query is trying to accomplish is search for `folder=>INBOX` and match the email query for either `recipient` or `from`.   Here's how I am trying to do it:

Query:

```
$query['$and'][]['$or'][]['to']['$regex'] = new MongoRegex("/".$_GET['term'].".*/i");
$query['$and'][]['$or'][]['from']['$regex'] = new MongoRegex("/".$_GET['term'].".*/i");
$query['$and'][]['$or'][]['recipient']['$regex'] = new MongoRegex("/".$_GET['term'].".*/i");
$query['$and'][]['folder'] = $_GET['folder'];
```

Print Pre:

```
Array
(
[$and] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [$or] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [to] => Array
                                    (
                                        [$regex] => MongoRegex Object
                                            (
                                                [regex] => example@example.com.*
                                                [flags] => i
                                            )
                                    )
                            )
                    )
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [$or] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [from] => Array
                                    (
                                        [$regex] => MongoRegex Object
                                            (
                                                [regex] => example@example.com.*
                                                [flags] => i
                                            )
                                    )
                            )
                    )
            )
        [2] => Array
            (
                [$or] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [recipient] => Array
                                    (
                                        [$regex] => MongoRegex Object
                                            (
                                                [regex] => example@example.com.*
                                                [flags] => i
                                            )
                                    )
                            )
                    )
            )
        [3] => Array
            (
                [folder] => INBOX
            )
    )
)
```

Comment: The only thing complex about this is that you have made it overcomplex for what should really be a simple operation. What are you really trying to do here? Search for input in "any" of the supplied fields ( to, from, recipient )? Have you looked at the manual page for [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/)? The syntax here has really wandered off the rails so I am wondering mostly why you would think this is correct.

Comment: @BlakesSeven Well what I am trying to accomplish with this query is search the collection for documents that match the field `folder=>INBOX` but also include the email in either `recipients` or `from` fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no [`$and`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/) condition involved. All you want to do is search each field with a supplied regular expression to see if it matches content in one of them. This is what an [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) operation does, and matches based on "either" condition supplied in an array of arguments as queries:

```js
{
    "folder": "INBOX",
    "$or": [
        { "to": /example@example.com.*/i },
        { "from": /example@example.com.*/i },
        { "recipient": /example@example.com.*/i }
    ]
}
```

Notated for PHP:

```
$query = array(
    'folder' => 'INBOX',
    '$or' => array(
        array( 'to' => new MongoRegex("/".$_GET['term'].".*/i") ),
        array( 'from' => new MongoRegex("/".$_GET['term'].".*/i") ),
        array( 'recipient' => new MongoRegex("/".$_GET['term'].".*/i") )
    )
)
```

And that is all there is to it.

**All** MongoDB query arguments are implicitly an "and" operation anyway, so there is very rarely any need to use the explicit operator. If it were used, then it would be the "wrapping" statement to both conditions:

```
{
    "$and": [ 
        { "folder": "INBOX" },
        { "$or": [
            { "to": /example@example.com.*/i },
            { "from": /example@example.com.*/i },
            { "recipient": /example@example.com.*/i }
        ]}
    ]
}
```

But you don't need to do that since it is already treated like this anyway.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't realize that all query arguments are implicitly 'and' operators.  And the way I had it was wrapped in an 'and' operator just as you do. Going to give this a run through, thanks for the assistance

Comment: @Chaosjosh surely you have seen something like this before `{ "number": { "$gte": 2, "$lt": 5 } }` which is another example of an implicit "and" to specify the range beetween the numbers. The language context is meant to be "easy" and not hard. Most conditions usually mean "and", therefore it is just the default.